# Java: class isn't recognized as being an instance of itself

Tags: java

I am trying to implement an associative operator for some matrix operations, and I must also use complex numbers. I encounter the following error after I run my program: *java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Double* , and I found out that this error is because an instanceof check passed as false, when it should be true.

Here is my code:

```
public void readFromFile(int noOfLines, int noOfColumns,T[][] matrix,T t) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File file = new File("matrix.txt");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfLines; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < noOfColumns; ++j)
        {
            if(t instanceof ComplexNumber)
                matrix[i][j] = (T)new ComplexNumber(s.nextInt(), 1);
            else if(t instanceof  Integer)
                matrix[i][j] = (T)new Integer(s.nextInt());
            else
                matrix[i][j] = (T)new Double(s.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem appears at this line

```
if(t instanceof ComplexNumber)
   matrix[i][j] = (T)new ComplexNumber(s.nextInt(), 1);
```

and the error at this line

```
matrix[i][j] = (T)new Double(s.nextInt());
```

Here is how I call the function

```
 ComplexNumber[][] matrix1 = new ComplexNumber[noOfLines][noOfColumns];
 file.readFromFile(noOfLines,noOfColumns,matrix1,ComplexNumber.class);
```

noOfLines and noOfColumns are integers, and readFromFile reads some strings from a file, and it should put them in the matrix1 array. 
How can I fix the problem, and why isn't ComplexNumber.class (or T t in my readFromFile arguments) and instanceOf ComplexNumber? Thank you.

EDIT: ComplexNumber class

```
public class ComplexNumber {
public double real;
public double imag;
public String output = "";

public ComplexNumber(double real, double imag) {
    this.real += real;
    this.imag += imag;
}

public ComplexNumber() {
    real = 0;
    imag = 0;
}

public double getReal() {
    return real;
}

public void setReal(double real) {
    this.real = real;
}

public double getImag() {
    return imag;
}

public void setImag(double imag) {
    this.imag = imag;
}

public void add(ComplexNumber num2) {
    this.real += num2.real;
    this.imag += num2.imag;
}

public void subtract(ComplexNumber num) {
    this.real -= num.real;
    this.imag -= num.imag;
}

public void print() {
    System.out.print(real + " " + imag + "i");
}

public String toString() {
    return real + " " + imag + "i";
}
}
```

Comment: What is `ComplexNumber`?

Comment: You are passing T as the type Class<ComplexNumber>.   You probably want T to be ComplexNumber instead.

Comment: A Java class is *not* an instance of itself.

Comment: Even once you fix your first error here, I believe you'll still have an unchecked warning, because `instanceof` does not guarantee that the types are identical, only that they are assignment-compatible. Rather than doing `instanceof` checks, it would probably be better to pass around a `Function<Integer, T>` object which the caller can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Class<T> clazz` instead of `T t` as the parameter (or pass in `new ComplexNumber` instead of `ComplexNumber.class`). Then you can replace `instanceof` with `clazz.equals(ComplexNumber.class)` (and the same for `Integer` and `Double`).

You're passing in `Class<ComplexNumber>` and your `else` clause is picking it up, since it's not a `ComplexNumber` or an `Integer`, it's a `Class`.

Comment: This is correct, but it might be good to mention `t.getClass().cast(...)`, which could potentially work here as well.

Comment: If `ComplexNumber` is not declared as `final`, one might want to use [`clazz.isAssignableFrom(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) instead of `clazz.equals(...)`.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer and the suggestions. The answer fixed my problem, but I will also look further in what the comments said.